# Compute the Galois group for $f(x) = (x^2-p)(x^2-q)(x^2-pq)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and determine all subfields of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

For $f(x) = (x^2-p)(x^2-q)(x^2-pq) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ where $p\neq q$ are primes I need to compute the Galois group for $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and determine all subfields of the splitting field.  Here is what I have so far:

There are 6 distinct roots of $f$, namely $-\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{p}, -\sqrt{q}, \sqrt{q}, -\sqrt{pq}, -\sqrt{pq}$ so $f$ is a separable polynomial.  The Galois group of a separable polynomial is the Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and since $\sqrt{pq} = \sqrt{p}\sqrt{q}$ it seems to be that the splitting field for $f$ would have to be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$.

This also seems to be the splitting field for the irreducible polynomial $(x^2-p)(x^2-q)$, so the Galois group permutes the roots of the irreducible factors and therefore the Galois group should consist of 1, $\tau$ which maps $\sqrt{p} \mapsto -\sqrt{p}$ and fixes $\sqrt{q}$, $\sigma$ which maps $\sqrt{q} \mapsto -\sqrt{q}$ and fixes $\sqrt{p}$ and the composition $\tau\sigma$.

In other words, $Gal(f(x)) = \{1, \sigma, \tau, \sigma\tau\}$ and I believe this to be isomorphic to the Klein-4 group.

As far as subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$ go, I believe that there are precisely 2: the intermediate field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$.

Is this reasoning correct, or am I making some incorrect assumptions?

Comment: @Arthur - Yes, I meant to put in the comma.  Should be fixed in edit

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{pq})\subset\mathbb Q(\sqrt p,\sqrt q)$ is another subfield, corresponding to the subgroup $\{1,\sigma\tau\}\subset\{1,\sigma,\tau,\sigma\tau\}$.

Comment: A non-cyclic group of order $4$ has five subgroups: one of order $1$, three of order $2$, and one of order $4$. So your field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$ has more than two properly-intermediate subfields.

Comment: You need to consider $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{pq})$